# Tkinter checkbutton interferences when filling in

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm working on a g.u.i. with tkinter. I'm currently trying to make a couple of  labelframes with several checkbuttons. The problem is that one checkbutton gets crossed in a window, and another in the other window get crossed too.

I've been looking for similar questions, but I've found none. Being a beginner, I don't really understand where the problem is.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from scipy.stats import linregress
import pandas as pd

window= tk.Tk()
#creating the  2 labelframes
models = tk.LabelFrame(window, text="Models", padx=10, pady=10)
models.grid(padx=10, pady=10, sticky='W')
param = tk.LabelFrame(window, text="params", padx=10, pady=10)
param.grid(column=0, row=10, sticky='W', padx= 10)
# adding checkbuttons to the first labelframe
lin_cb = tk.Checkbutton(models, text="linear regression")
lin_cb.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='W')
nlin_cb = tk.Checkbutton(models, text="non-linear regression")
nlin_cb.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky='W')
#labels for second labelframe
tk.Label(param, text="substate").grid(row=1, sticky='W')
tk.Label(param, text="velocity").grid(row=2, sticky='W')
tk.Label(param, text="if inhibited").grid(row=3, sticky='W')
tk.Label(param, text="inibitor").grid(row=4, sticky='W')
#checkbutton
su_M=tk.Checkbutton(param, text='M')
su_M.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='W')
su_mM=tk.Checkbutton(param, text='mM')
su_mM.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky='W')

window.mainloop()
```

Before continuing with the program extracting the information from the crossed checkbutton, I have to understand how to solve this problem. Thanks to everyone. I hope that I gave you all the necessary information. I tried to summarise the code as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a `Checkbutton`, you need to create tkinter variables and associate them with each `Checkbutton`.

```
import tkinter as tk

window= tk.Tk()
models = tk.LabelFrame(window, text="Models", padx=10, pady=10)
models.grid(padx=10, pady=10, sticky='W')
param = tk.LabelFrame(window, text="params", padx=10, pady=10)
param.grid(column=0, row=10, sticky='W', padx= 10)

all_vars = [tk.IntVar() for _ in range(4)] #create 4 IntVars in one go
for i in all_vars : #set all vars to 0
    i.set(0)

lin_cb = tk.Checkbutton(models, text="linear regression",variable=all_vars[0])  #set variable for each checkbutton
lin_cb.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='W')
nlin_cb = tk.Checkbutton(models, text="non-linear regression",variable=all_vars[1])
nlin_cb.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky='W')

tk.Label(param, text="substate").grid(row=1, sticky='W')
tk.Label(param, text="velocity").grid(row=2, sticky='W')
tk.Label(param, text="if inhibited").grid(row=3, sticky='W')
tk.Label(param, text="inibitor").grid(row=4, sticky='W')

su_M=tk.Checkbutton(param, text='M',variable=all_vars[2])
su_M.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='W')
su_mM=tk.Checkbutton(param, text='mM',variable=all_vars[3])
su_mM.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky='W')

window.mainloop()
```